# ng build/serve not working ERROR in template

Tags: angular, npm, angular8, serve

Having issues trying to build/serve an app created using nx/Angular 8. There are 3 issues:

```
WARNING in Entry point '@angular/material' contains deep imports ... (rxjs/observable)
ERROR in template must be a string
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Any help in resolving the issue is appreciated.

> The Browser displays: Cannot GET /

The full error is:

```
ng serve abc-app
  0% compiling
Compiling @angular/material : es2015 as esm2015                                                            10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.01 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 155 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.82 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 340 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-08-14T02:06:54.559Z - Hash: 352c09b777f8eeb3654d - Time: 12744ms

WARNING in Entry point '@angular/material' contains deep imports into 'C:/ui/node_modules/rxjs/Subject', 'C:/ui/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription', 'C:/ui/node_modules/rxjs/observable/fromEvent', 'C:/ui/node_modules/rxjs/observable/merge', 'C:/ui/node_modules/rxjs/observable/of', 'C:/ui/node_modules/rxjs/Observable', 'C:/ui/node_modules/rxjs/observable/throw', 'C:/workspace/ui/node_modules/rxjs/observable/forkJoin'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.

ERROR in template must be a string
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Please try to remove all node_modules and reinstall again.

Comment: Thanks @SachinShah ..did just that. But still the same issue.

Comment: Which NPM version are you using?

Comment: I think this is the version issue. Please check Prerequisite for Angular8. And if possible upgrade angular version and also clear the cache. For details please check this link . https://www.javatpoint.com/angular-8

Comment: @Harry I'm facing this issue too. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @snort...had to upgrade to Angular 8 and remove all Angular 4 usages